# Retaining class instance list contents while multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Let's say I have some class called dog:

```
class dog():
     def __init__(self, name, age):
          self.name = name
          self.age = age
          self.fleas = []
```

Now let's say I have a list of names,

```
names = ["bob", "joe", "dave"]
```

and I create a list doing the following:

```
dogs = [dog(name, index) for index, name in enumerate(names)]  # Creates a list "dogs" that has 3 dog classes in it, named bob, joe, david, with ages 0, 1, 2 respectively.
```

Now I have a dictionary of fleas,

```
global_fleas = {"bob":[flea_43], "joe":[flea_20], "dave":[flea_3]}
```

and there is some separate method `flea_mod()` that modifies this dictionary so that the flea number for each dog is changed to some random number like flea_50. There will only be one flea for each dog in this dictionary.

I can append the flea in global_fleas to its corresponding dog by doing the following:

```
def dirty_dog(dog):
     dog.fleas.append(global_fleas[dog.name])
```

Here's the kicker. I want to multiprocess this loop. Here's what I have right now:

```
while True:
    flea_mod()  # This randomizes the flea_number for each dog in the global_flea dictionary
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=len(dogs))
    [pool.apply_async(dirty_dog, dog) for dog in dogs]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

So the problem is each dog object does not retain its fleas list every time the loop is run. I want the fleas list for each dog to be retained at the end of each loop, so after two loops, each dog will have two fleas, and so on. Any ideas? I'm guessing I'll have to pickle something.

Comment: Data is not shared between processes by default. `dirty_dog()` (if you were call it correctly) would work on a copy of each dog in a child process. Why do you want to use multiprocessing here?

Comment: I understand that Sebastian. What I'm trying to do is keep each dog's fleas list each time it loops, so that each dog's fleas list gets longer. I just made this dog stuff up as a simple analogy for what I'm really trying to do. Multiprocessing what I'm really trying to do would make things go much faster.

Comment: Creating a new pool in each iteration of this loop means each iteration must spawn new processes, which has a large amount of OS overhead. Think "create once, process lots" when it comes to using process pools.

Answer (score 1):

The multiprocessing docs advise against shared state when possible, but you could probably use a managed dictionary to achieve your goals:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

(See the server based Manager section.)

This way you could alter a single managed object based on your core logic and the processing nodes would see the updated version. You'll have to try it out in your code to see what the best sharing setup is (if any!).

Comment: Thanks. I have a version of my code that uses Manager, but it is much more complicated.

Comment: @user2197885 My answer offers a simpler (imho) solution.

Answer (score 0):

J.F Sebastian is correct. The reason you are not seeing mutations in the loop is that they occur in another process. It seems that you are not very familiar with processes; you should consider [learning more about them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29).

You want to take the results from the pool, and copy them over to your local dogs. One way to do this is to modify your loop to look something like this:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=some_number_of_processes)
while True:
    flea_mod()
    results = [pool.appy_async(dirty_dog, dog) for dog in dogs]
    for result, dog in zip(results, dogs):
        # I assume that dirty_dog returns the updated dog.
        dog.update(result.get(timeout=some_positive_number_of_seconds))
```

A couple of things to note:

1. You should avoid creating a new pool during each iteration. This avoid the overhead of process (pool) creation.
2. `some_number_of_processes` can be `< len(dogs)`! Each process creates some overhead; therefore, there is a point of diminishing returns. It's usually better to overestimate a little vs. underestimating. However, grossly overestimating is easily avoided, unless you're really lazy.

If you are using Python 3.2 or higher, and dirty_dog is not CPU bound (e.g. touches disk often), then consider using a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) instead; that way, modifications don't need to be copied, because the threads will operate on the same objects, not copies.

Comment: `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` provides the same interface but uses threads.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `dirty_dog()` does some lengthy computations that are not shown here; multiprocessing won't improve performance (all benefits would be eaten by copying the data back and forth).

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def dirty_dog(i):
    dog = dogs[i]
    dog.fleas.append(global_fleas[dog.name])
    dogs[i] = dog

def init(global_fleas_, dogs_):
    global global_fleas, dogs
    global_fleas, dogs = global_fleas_, dogs_

if __name__=="__main__":
    manager = mp.Manager()
    dogs = manager.list(dogs)
    pool = mp.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=[global_fleas, dogs])
    for _ in range(3):
       flea_mod()
       pool.map(dirty_dog, range(len(dogs)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```